# Overlaying a lineCollection on a plot in matplotlib - how to get the two to line up.

Tags: python, matplotlib, transform

I'm trying to do a heat map over a shape file in python. I need to make quite a few of these so don't want to read in the .shp every time.

Instead, I thought I could create a lineCollection instance of the map boundaries and overlay the two images. Problem is - I can't seem to get the two to line up correctly.

Here is the code, where linecol is the lineCollection object.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.contourf(xi,yi,zi)
ax.add_collection(linecol, autolim = False)
plt.show()
```

Is there an easy way to fix the limits of linecol to match those of the other plot? I've had a play with set_xlim and transforms.Bbox, but can't seem to manage it.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Transforms are tricky because of the various coordinate systems involved. See http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/transforms_tutorial.html.

I managed to scale a `LineCollection` to the appropriate size like this. The key was to realize that I needed to add `+ ax.transData` to the new transform I set on the `LineCollection`. (When you don't set any transform on an artist object, `ax.transData` is the default. It converts data coordinates into display coordinates.)

```
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.collections as mc
import matplotlib.transforms as tx
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()

# Heat map spans 1 x 1.
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
xs = ys = np.arange(0, 1.01, 0.01)
zs = np.random.random((101,101))
ax.contourf(xs, ys, zs, cmap=cm.autumn)

lines = mc.LineCollection([[(5,1), (9,5), (5,9), (1,5), (5,1)]])
# Shape spans 10 x 10. Resize it to 1 x 1 before applying the transform from
# data coords to display coords.
trans = tx.Affine2D().scale(0.1) + ax.transData
lines.set_transform(trans)
ax.add_collection(lines)

plt.show()
```

(Output here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDNN8.png Not enough reputation to post inline.)
[image]

It should be easy to modify this if you need the shape translated or scaled unequally on x and y.